# Unable to start Android Emulator in Android Studio 2.3

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am unable to start the Android emulator in Android Studio.

Below is the screenshot of Android Studio and the emulator loading.
Also the warning from the anti-virus program.

[image: Warning]

Below is the command prompt logs for emulator.

```
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
emulator: goldfish_events.have-dpad: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-trackball: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-camera: true
emulator: goldfish_events.have-keyboard: true
emulator: goldfish_events.have-lidswitch: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-touch: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-multitouch: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Even this question is not related to stackoverflow.Please take care from next time .

From what you're saying, it's obvious **Kaspersky** is blocking the data stream. Try this...

```
Open Kaspersky>Click on Settings on the top-right corner>Click on Network on the left> Click on the Select... button on the right.

On the top uncheck port
```

> HTTP:80.

On the list below please uncheck any browser you use.

Click OK to exit all those windows and try again.